# Illegal characters in path when linking c++ objects with Visual C++ for Linux Development

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, linker

I have created a c++ app with visual studio 2015 for windows.I also like to run this app on linux distros so I installed on windows the Visual C++ for Linux Development plug-in. I also created an Ubuntu 16.04 VM to target. The ssh connection was successful as well as the file transfer to the linux relevant folders. The compilation completed successfully but since I also use shared libraries when the linking process began I got the following error:

```
 Illegal characters in path
```

for the line

```
Ld Condition="'@(RemoteLink)' != ''"
```

of the file:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.Common.targets

I also tried it on Visual studio 2017 but the same result. I enter the library path both on VC++ directories and in the field "Shared library search path" of the linker but the error persisted. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted by Bernie, this message appears when there is a linker error, typically `g++` can't find a library.
Its been [discussed here](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/122).

Turn up the build output level and all will be revealed. In `Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/Build and Run` set `MSBuild project output verbosity` to `Normal`.

Answer (score 0):

I had had the same problem today after having migrated a Linux C++ project from Netbeans IDE to Visual Studio 2017.

Surprisingly this linker error message '*illegal characters in path*' disappeared when I completed the required linker options at VS2017 (menu: project properties / Linker / Command line).

I my case I had to add the '-lrt' option. At netbeans IDE I got the error message 'undefined reference to 'clock_gettime'' when not using the '-lrt' option.

At Visual Studio it seems that the linker error message fails or is messed up and therefore I just got that '*illegal characters in path*' message.

So possibly it could help you if you look for the explicit linker options you gave to the windows project version and try to add it also to the linux version?