# Building protobuf for Linux using VS2017

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2017, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have configured VS2017 to build Linux C++ by remote building on a Linux Mint VM.
I tried a simple C++ program and it compiles and executes fine, the thing is that now I need to add a generated protobuf source and the linking fails constantly.

On the Linux VM the protobuf generated files are building correctly and I was able to execute the gRPC examples.

The errors I get when I build from VS2017 are a lot of:

*undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal'*

and there is also this one

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.targets(262,5): error : Illegal characters in path.*

I think this is a VS2017 remote compilation configuration issue, but I don't know what could it be.

Has it happened to you? Do you know how to solve this issue?

Thanks

**SOLUTION:** I the project properties go to *Linker > All Options > Library dependencies* and add: *protobuf;pthread;grpc++;grpc*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43290986/illegal-characters-in-path-when-linking-c-objects-with-visual-c-for-linux-de/43324192#43324192) explains the "Illegal characters in path" message.

Does `protobuf` link to any libraries on the Linux system? Assuming you're not using CMake, have you added the libraries andtheir path(s) to the Visual Studio project - `Library Dependencies` and `Additional Library Directories`.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570103/g-cant-link-curl-lib-files/45578921#45578921) might help with specifying libraries.

Comment: Hey Stan, thanks to the second link I saw it tried to use pkg-config, in my case that didn't work, but I executed it on the linux console to see what it generated and it was "lprotobuf -pthread -lpthread -lgrpc++ -lgrpc" so what I did is to add that to Linker > All Options > Library dependencies and voila, it started building fine.