# VS2017 Linux C++ development with Protobuf environment

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2017, protocol-buffers

I've been building my own c++ linux application in vs2017, using the built in tools that connect to my virtual ubuntu VM. I have gotten to a point where I want to integrate protobuf into my project, but I am running into issues as to how to do so.

I have installed the protobuf libraries and compiler on my VM using Google's UNIX C++ installation guide. And I am able to compiler without issue. After I compiled one message, I brought the files back over to my windows side so that I can bring them into my VS project. However that causes all sorts of errors, mainly:

undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal'

So I went through a previous Stack Overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536952/building-protobuf-for-linux-using-vs2017) where the user ran the following command on the VM:

pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf

and the took the text in that output, and put it into his Linker > All Options > Library dependencies in his VS project on the windows side. For me, that was:

-pthread -lprotobuf -pthread -lpthread

However, when I compile, I get cannot find. I've been trying to find out what are the best practices when doing linux development through VS2017, and wanting to use protobuf. Any help on how to get that entire chain working would be great.